# htaccess rewrite acting funny

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is my redirect rule to redirect inside a `public/` directory.

File inside `site` (example directory)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ public/index.php?r=$1 [NC,L]
```

What this does is create a funky effect.

```
site/a/b/c --> site/a/b/c/b/c
                      // ^ b/c is repeated and the params are a/b/c
```

Inside a public directory .htaccess file has

```
RewriteEngine On
```

If I remove this line, `r` gets `public/index.php` not `a/b/c`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Its still the same `a/b/c/b/c`

Comment: Edited it again, can you try now?

Comment: That one worked. Thanks. What was the problem with my htaccess?

Comment: As you can see you had some redundant rules. What you wanted to do can be done in 2 rules as I showed above. Due to extra rules your URL is subject to multiple rewrites and becoming malformed in the end.

Comment: This does not exclude files or directory match. How to make direct files like `site.com/js/a.js` to `site.com/public/js/a.js`? I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]` but this makes the file accecible as `public/js/a.js`

Comment: I left a comment for you on other question.